# How to clone a repository from linux to my window desktop using gitExtension

Tags: java, linux, git, window, git-extensions

I'm newbie to Git Extension , My central repository is put on linux server and we are using our own window desktop for the developemnt . Just wanna know how can configure Git Extension to pull source from linux server?
[image]

Account for git in linux : misshare
Path the source was put in linux : /home/misshare
My server ip : 10.10.10.1
[image]

I've tried to put input misshare@10.10.10.1:/home/misshare  nor ssh://misshare@10.10.10.1:/home/misshare in repository to clone but it doesn't work.

Many thanks.

Comment: *but it doesn't work.* is not an error description. Please explain what it means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it doesn't matter if your git repository is on Linux Server and you are working on Windows machine. You can still clone the repository, make changes and commit.

In the repository to clone text field, you must key in something like

```
> user@server:/path/to/git-repo/.git
```

In your case it should be

```
> misshare@10.10.10.1:/home/misshare/.git
```

Comment: Thank you . at the end i found that after changing the command to this , i have to change the method from Putty to OpenSSH and it works .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your windows desktop has access to the linux machine. For the rest....

https://serverfault.com/questions/463811/git-clone-pull-across-local-network